# Enabling propel plugin in Netbeans for Symfony Php framework

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I am new to Symfony framework. I got Symfony (v1.4.8) on my Netbeans 6.8 and also got the initial success page.

Now, I want to Configure a database using Propel ORM Tool. But in Netbeans I am getting Doctrine as the default tool enabled. I am not even getting the PROPEL commands in my Run Commands window. I configured Netbeans for Symfony as per the instructions at: 
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/symfony-screencast.html

I tried editing "ProjectConfiguration.class" but of no success. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: An old post, but worth noting: Netbeans probably isn't relevant here. If you `cd` to your project folder and type `./symfony` then you'll get what you see in the Netbeans UI - which is provided just as a small shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys... I seemed to have solved it the stupid way. I fixed the Properties.ini and ProjectConfiguration.class.php in the Config folder of my project (which I was doing for a long time) and then restarted my NetBeans.

I had all the Propel Modules loaded up...

Comment: Can you be more precise on how you solved the problem, please?  I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the /config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php edit the line

```
$this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrinePlugin');
```

to load the Propel plugin instead:

```
$this->enablePlugins('sfPropelPlugin');
```

Also in the /config/properties.ini set

```
orm=Propel
```

Comment: For the most recent version of Propel (1.6), you'll want to enable `sfPropelORMPlugin` instead. `sfPropelPlugin` is for the embedded version of Propel, which I think is version 1.4.